# Selenium IDE - selectFrame issues

Tags: html, selenium-ide

Im new to Selenium IDE on Firefox and having iFrame issues. When Selenium runs "selectframe" I get an error iframe not found. Im not familiar with xpath or webdriver so I wouldn't know how to fix it using that. I've attached a screenshot of the iFrame. I also can't find the name of the iFrame.

Error message is : "[error] Element recurlyHostedField:number not found"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.test.com/" />
<title>LCPayment</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">LCPayment</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/all-access/subscription/payment/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=AA_LC_TRIAL_MONTHLY</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=first_name</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=last_name</td>
    <td>testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=address1</td>
    <td>5643 street</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=city</td>
    <td>los angeles</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=state</td>
    <td>label=CO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=postal_code</td>
    <td>90023</td>
</tr>
<tr> \\this  is where the error happens. when I run selectFrame an error appears "[error] Element recurlyHostedField:number not found"
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    **<td>recurlyHostedField:number</td>**
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=recurly-hosted-field-input</td>
    <td>4111 1111 1111 1111</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byen4.png)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You've shown the HTML, but what are you trying in Selenium IDE? Please read [ask].

Comment: Chrome worked like a charm